# Redirect URL with an 'www.abcd.com/?page_id=XXX' format in WordPress 4.4.2 - Apache 2.4.12

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have redesigned an entire WordPress website and while setting up 301 in my .htaccess file I was enable to redirect URLs with the following format:

www.abcd.com/?page_id=XXX

I have tried two things:

**Number 1**

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectRule %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=XXX
Redirect 301 oldpage.php newpage.php
```

**Number 2**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=XXX$
RewriteRule ^page.php$ http://www.example.com/content/page? [R=301,L]
```

None of these worked. I don't have any problems redirecting the other URLs with a 'www.abcd.com/xxxxx format though. The problem is just with 'www.abcd.com/?page_id=XXX' URLs.

I also spent a good amount of time reading through the apache website.

Comment: **When should I vote down?**

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect. 

Not sure I understand why this -1........

Comment: The first attempt there is incorrect as `Redirect` has nothing to do with `mod_rewrite`. Your second attempt is close, but you are checking for the `id=` query string, instead of the `page_id=` query string.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Really appreciate your help.